# How to handle all missing leading zeros case in datetime strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

```
function convertDate(date: any) {
    
    if(typeof date == 'string') {
        date = new Date(date).toISOString()
    }
    console.log('new')
    console.log(date)

    if (props.isUTC) {
        return date.utc(true).toISOString()
    }

    return date.toISOString()
}
```

I need to write a date function that accepts any string and outputs at the end a datetime in this format: yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm

The issue is that the above function throws an error when we send something without a leading zero. Is there a way to fix it easily?

```
2022-08-03 03:55 //this works
2022-08-03 3:55 //this doesn't work
2022-08-3 03:55 //this doesn't work
```

I did try with something like this:

```
if (!date.isValid()) {

    let day = date.getDate()
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1
    const year = date.getFullYear()
    let hour =  date.getHours()
    let minute =  date.getMinutes()
    let second =  date.getSeconds()

    if (month.toString().length < 2) month = '0' + month
    if (hour.toString().length < 2) hour = '0' + hour
    if (day.toString().length < 2) day = '0' + day
    if (minute.toString().length < 2) minute = '0' + minute
    if (second.toString().length < 2) second = '0' + second
    console.log('invalid')
    
    date = new Date(year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second)
    console.log(date)
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Can you use a library like moment.js?

Comment: "*I need to write a date function that accepts any string…*" is not possible. It can be done for a limited set of formats, but there is no universal timestamp parser that works without knowing the input format.

Comment: I can use moment.js. I'd rather use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split and join, padding each string with `0` until length of 2 using `String.padStart()`

```js
console.log(fixDateTime("2022-08-03 3:55"));
console.log(fixDateTime("2022-8-3 3:55"));

function pad2(str, sepa) {
  var arr = str.split(sepa);
  arr = arr.map(item => ("" + item).padStart(2, '0'));
  str = arr.join(sepa);
  return str;
}

function fixDateTime(str) {
  var arr = str.split(/\s+/);
  var result = pad2(arr[0], '-') + " " + pad2(arr[1], ':');
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Consider `"2022-8-3 3:55".replace(/\d+/g, c=>c.padStart(2,'0'))`. ;-)

Comment: Not only shorter but makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

You can format the date using the internationalization api like bellow :

```
function convertDate(date){
  const newDate = new Date(date);
  if(!newDate) return console.log('Invalid input');

  const options = {
     year: 'numeric',
     month: '2-digit',
     day: '2-digit',
     hour: '2-digit',
     minute: '2-digit', 
  };

  // Using the internationalization api (Intl)
  // syntx: Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, options).format(value);
  // locale is the langue code. eg. ('en-GB' for Great Britain English) 
  // option is an object with the formatting options as above.
 // value is the value to be formated.


  return Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(newDate);  
}
```

// Note: you can use the Intl api to format numbers, currencies... you can check it out [here](https://%20//%20Note:%20you%20can%20also%20use%20the%20Intl%20api%20to%20format%20numbers,%20currencies...%20you%20can%20check%20it%20out%20on%20%5Bhere%5D%5B1%5D) for more info.

Comment: The OP's issue is parsing. The *Intl* formatter is not ideal where exact formatting is required since it relies on the [CLDR's definition](https://cldr.unicode.org) of various formats for languages, which may change over time.

Comment: @RobG maybe i didn't understand the question as well as i thought i did. anyways where do you think the error is coming from '2022-08-03 3:55' is a valid argument for the Date object. and what is the props.isUTC in the second if statement?

Comment: '2022-08-03 3:55' is not "valid" in that it's not supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. In Safari it produces an invalid *Date*.